# Intersection of principal ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $x,y$ be nonzero elements in a commutative ring $R$. Is $(x)\cap (y)$ always finitely generated?
What if we further assume that $R$ is an integral domain? Can we construct non-Noetherian non-local semi-local integral domains whose every maximal ideal is principal (in the local case, there are certain valuation rings.)?

Comment: To your first question about $R$ being a domain and $(x)\cap (y)$ not being finitely generated, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296653

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Comment: One way to force finite generation of $(x)\cap (y)$ is to make this ideal equal to $(xy)$ , and one nice case where this happens is that $x$ is not a zero divisor on $R/(y)$